# User Group Level Login

Tags: users

Hi everyone I am creating a WordPress website where I have to create multilevel user authentication, for example, one user label for just a registered user second level for students who purchased any course Third Level for their parents 4th label for teacher fifth level for admin and 6 level for super admin who can control everyone.

I am able to to use this in Joomla using user group and level but I don't know how to define this type of multilevel user group in WordPress and how to assign separate and specific pages to any specific user group.

I am waiting for your reply if anyone has answer please reply.

Comment: Hello! Can you add commas and full stops to your sentences? It's difficult to understand and leads to ambiguous sentences. Also, plugin recommendations are offtopic on this site

Comment: Hello I have removed plugin recommendation, now can you please help me

Comment: I've reopened and made some edits, but can you clarify what it is you're describing? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, are you trying to create user roles?